# any type with specific parameter

Tags: kotlin

I want to write a kotlin function that can filter lists.

The filtering I want to do is pretty much an ID whitelisting, so imagine that I have a list of string IDs that are allowed. Then the function should remove all objects of the input list that have an ID not in the whitelist. Pretty basic stuff really.

The problem I guess is that I want it really generic. And I am wondering if it is possible in kotlin to take in a list of `Any`, but that have a property `id`?
Or is it only possible by creating an interface that all objects need to implement?

Comment: You can make a generic function that accepts a lambda supposed to return the id based on the item. Something like `fun <T> List<T>.filterId(getId: (T) -> String): List<T>`. This way it's the caller's responsibility to give you a way to retrieve the id, and it could be as simple as passing a function reference, e.g. `aList.filterId(ItemType::id)`. A somewhat similar example is `sortedBy` in the standard lib

Comment: @gpunto any particular reason you wrote this as a comment not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
fun <T> List<T>.filterUnknownIds(getId: T.() -> String): List<T> = filter { it.getId() in whitelistedIds }
```

Assuming `whitelistedIds` is a list of strings. I didn't compile the code as I'm on mobile but should work.

Comment: this might be a bit off-topic, but is it possible to write such an extension function as a member of another class? Basically have a service class own the List object and filter it via a repository class that needs a database connection (thus not possible to have it as a top level extension)

Comment: @munHunger The simplest way would be to not have it as an extension function but just a normal function of the repository with the list as a parameter. Or you write the extension function in your service class where you have access to the repository as a property. 
Either way, I want to recommand if you have a function that makes a database request in the back it should reflect it in the name. If you use coroutines make it suspending.